# Use Selenium findElements() in Array.map loop/await on Promise not possible

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium, I need to extend my CSS filter using `Array.map`, cause CSS isn't powerfull enough for my filtering. But I'm running into issues about promises and callbacks. So what I want is the following:

```
    let elements = await browserDriver.findElements(By.css('.my-selector'));
    let filteredElements = elements.map(element => {
        let subElements = await element.findElements(By.css('.my-sub-selector'));
        if(subElements.length > 0){
            return element;
        }
    });
```

But on `await element.findElements(By.css('.my-sub-selector'));` I got the error `await expression is only allowed within an async function`. That's not comprehensible for me: `findElements` returns a `Promise<WebElement[]>`. As I understand, Promises are async and I can use async to avoid dirty nested callbacks.

This seems generally true, cause in the first line async is working as I expect it, but not in the `Array.map` call. There I need a direct return value, so using the `then` function of the promise is sadly not possible...

Comment: Can you show the whole function code ?

Comment: Can you try to change your second await code slightly to `let subElements = await Promise.all(element.findElements(By.css('.my-sub-selector')));`

Comment: This error occurs when an `await` is present in a regular `function(){ }`. Your code needs to be placed in an async function: `async function() { await ... }`.  You may also need to deactivate the ControlFlow : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969